# Vue.js wait for axios response before executing another function

Tags: vue.js, axios

my app needs token for every api call it makes.
my problem is the functions are being executed before i make `gettoken()`

so my question is how to stop vue from executing code until `gettoken()` is finished

**My Code**
main.js

```
methods:
{
  getValidToken() {
    if (VueCookies.get('token') === null) {
      let requestBody = {
        client_id: "shopping_oauth_client",
        client_secret: "shopping_oauth_secret"
      };
      let requestHeader = {
        Authorization:
          "Basic c2hvcHBpbmdfb2F1dGhfY2xpZW50OnNob3BwaW5nX29hdXRoX3NlY3JldA",
      };
      window.axios
        .post(window.main_urls["get-token"], requestBody, {
          headers: requestHeader
        })
        .then(response => {
          VueCookies.set("aamts2124222", response.data.access_token);
          return VueCookies.get("token");
        });
    } else {
      return VueCookies.get("token");
    }
  }
}
```

cart.vue

```
getCartContent() {
  let requestHeader = {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + this.getValidToken()
  };
  window.axios
    .get(window.main_urls["get-cart"], { headers: requestHeader })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.data.error === "Cart is empty") {
        this.emptyCart = true;
        this.loading = false;
      } else {
        this.loading = false;
        this.cartData = response.data.data;
      }
    });
},
```

So how to wait to `getValidToken()` then execute `getcartcontent()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `async-await` in your `getCartContent()` method.

Like so:

```
async getCartContent() {
  let token = await this.getValidToken();
  let requestHeader = {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token
  };
```

This will make sure that your `requestHeader` will have token before it executes that line.